# Can I reference a specific function overload?

Tags: kotlin, kdoc

Given the following code

```
fun example() {}

fun example(name: String) {}
```

How can I reference a specific function? I.e. `example()` or `example(String)`?

Using `[example]` I can't specify which exactly function I want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At this time you can't. Dokka generates all overloads of a function on a single page, and the link points to that page, so you can simply specify the overload you need as text: "the one-argument overload of [example]".

There is an [open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15984) for adding the possibility to link to a specific overload, but we aren't too happy with the proposed syntax, so we don't have a definite plan to support this.

Comment: This also means that quick documentation inside Intellij doesn't go to the correct function.