# How to use JavaDocs @see on overload method in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, overloading, javadoc

I try to add @see in Kotlin on overload methods, but it can't assign arguments in `[]`.

```
/**
 * @see [hello(name)] ???
 */
fun hello() {
  ...
}

fun hello(val name:String) {

}
```

Comment: it's a [known bug/missing feature](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/issues/80)

Comment: Duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855908/can-i-reference-a-specific-function-overload, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59400005/in-kotlin-documentation-kdoc-is-it-possible-to-link-to-a-specific-overloaded and maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956535/copy-kdoc-docs-from-one-method-to-another